# How to watch a macro on visual studio? (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a C++ code that makes extensive use of macros, these macros were created to optimize running time so function inlining is not an option (real-time requirements).

What I'd really like is for these macros do be recognized by visual studio's watch window so I can debug properly, is there any way to achieve this?

Is there any extension to help with this?

Comment: While it's nearly impossible to say with absolute certainty, my immediate guess would be that neither is possible. By run-time, the macros have been expanded and disappeared.

Comment: Pretty sure you cant unless there is some visual studio specific wizardry possible. Macros aren't even seen by the compiler and have no presence in the end machine code. You could consider swapping the macros for functions in a debug version and doing your debugging and swapping back, Not ideal but that's what macros get you.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what that means, watching a macro. Macros are little more than (somewhat intelligent) compile-time text substitution.

Comment: Just to be clear: you want to have Visual Studio "watch" the values produced by a `#define MACRO expression` ..??

Comment: I want visual studio to expand the macro when it's entered in the "watch" window

Comment: I seems pretty plausible for me for an extension to parse the file the user is currently looking at and substitute for the macros expansion when entered in the watch, it wouldn't work for macros defined in other files though (#includes for example), for that it would be necessary an integration with the compiler